# MongoDB Compass can not be opened in macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-catalina, compass

I have installed MongoDB Compass on my Mac. But when I try to open it I get an error message in the screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: app can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.]

Answer (score 4):

"macOS includes a technology called Gatekeeper, that's designed to ensure that only trusted software runs on your Mac."

If you want to open it anyway, open it's enclosing folder with clicking "Show in Finder", then ctrl + right click on the app and click to Open.

Further information is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202491).